# How to use more than one embla carousel in a single webpage

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to integrate embla in angular. it works when I have a single slider in my page but when I try to make it more than one, the code breaks guess I'm getting something wrong in my ts code.

I followed this example on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-embla?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Is it possbile to have more than one on a page with embla?

Comment: Is this what you needed? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-embla-twfhsc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you so much

Comment: Have you perhaps tried integrating nav buttons and pagination with it? It's not working though I tried following the steps used by the team on codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/embla-carousel-dragfree-qe0vk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the angular embla stackblitz sample to include navigation buttons and pagination similar to the code sample that you shared. I simply took the code from the codesandbox sample and made it work with angular. There could be better ways to do this. Also, in my opinion, it would be better to use a carousel plugin that is built to be used with angular.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-embla-twfhsc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you perhaps have suggestions about plugins easier to use with angular. That can be used as a product carousel card with multiple slides. I appreciate what you've done.

Comment: I have not used it but this looks good: https://ngx-universal.herokuapp.com/#/carousel

Comment: Checked it out. Highly useful. Thank you.